# Editing A Label By Tag iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, label

I've looked for this everywhere and I can't find a solution...

**My Goal:** I'm trying to edit a label in my storyboard without creating an outlet specifically for that label (I have 36 labels).

**Problem:** I tried this basic line of code that I found on another Stack Overflow question, but it didn't succeed and I got an error...

```
UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[self viewWithTag:71];
```

Error: `No visible @interface for 'ViewControllerTwo' declares the selector 'viewWithTag:'`

Any help will be appreciated...

Comment: Why don't you want to create an outlet again?

Comment: Because I would rather just reference each label by a tag rather than creating outlets for each label.

Comment: Sounds like a bad design to me. Use an `IBOutletCollection` and connect all the labels up to that and then you essentially just work with an array of labels

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change your code to

```
                                    |
                                    v
UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:71];
```

`UIViewController` does not have `viewWithTag:`, `UIView` does

Answer (score 4):

viewwithTag is a method on UIView not on UIViewController.  You'll probably have to call it like this:

```
UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:71];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `self.view`:

```
UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:71];
```

Answer (score 0):

just as @Paul.s said, `IBOutletCollection` may be a better way. Just in case you need `IBOutletCollection` :

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutletCollection(UILabel) NSArray *labels;
```

Or in Swift:

```
@IBOutlet var imageViews: [UIImageView]!
```